# Unable to call method after class instantiation

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
var myclass = {
    init:function () {
        this.customer = null;
    },
    test : function(data){
      alert(testing);
    }
};
```

I am instantiating `myclass` like above, and later on I am trying to call a method `test` of the class, but it doesnt work. What am I doing wrong?

```
var testClass = new myclass.init();
testClass.customer = 'John B';
testClass.test(); //doesnt alert 1
```

Instead of getting the alert, for some reason I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'test'

Comment: should you be using class as a variable name?

Comment: Just pointing it out. class is a reserved keyword in JS. YOu may want to use something else like clazz

Comment: I changed the class to testClass ..still same

Comment: You've instantiated `init()`, it doesn't contain `test()`.

Comment: should he have that extra ","?

Comment: I initialized the class using that init...but now I need to get the other methods in the class

Comment: @Autolycus There's no other methods in that "class" `init`. Please read bfavaretto's answer.

Answer (score 4):

You have to define your "class" as a constructor function, not an object literal:

```
var MyClass = function(){
    this.init = function () {
        this.customer = null;
    };

    this.test = function(data){
      alert('testing');
    };
};
var testClass = new MyClass();
testClass.init();
testClass.customer = 'John B';
testClass.test(); //alerts 'testing'
```

Then the `init` function is not really needed, you can add that logic to the constructor itself:

```
var MyClass = function(){
    this.customer = null;

    this.test = function(data){
      alert('testing');
    };
};
var testClass = new MyClass();
testClass.customer = 'John B';
testClass.test(); //alerts 'testing'
```

You can also add your methods to `MyClass.prototype` instead of declaring them inside the constructor. For the difference between the two, refer to [Use of 'prototype' vs. 'this' in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript).

Finally, if you want to stick to your object literal, you have to use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create):

```
var myclass = {
    init:function () {
        this.customer = null;
    },
    test : function(data){
      alert('testing');
    }
};

var testClass = Object.create(myclass);
testClass.customer = 'John B';
testClass.test(); //alerts 'testing'
```

Answer (score 2):

Another implementation, with some explanations:

```
var MyClass = function() {
    this.customer = null;
};

// Any functions need to be added to the prototype,
// and should use the keyword this to access member fields.
// Doing this allows for a performance gain over recreating a new function definition
// every time we create the object, as would be the case with this.test = function() { ... }
MyClass.prototype.test = function(data){
    alert('testing');
};

// At this point, MyClass is a constructor function with all of it's
// prototype methods set, ready to be instantiated.

var testClass = new MyClass();
testClass.customer = 'John B'; // May also want to consider moving this into the constructor function as a parameter.
testClass.test();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wqvev/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the test method a prototype of init. Like this...

```
var myclass = {
    init:function () {
        this.customer = null;
    },
    test : function(data){
      alert(testing);
    },
};

myclass.init.prototype = myclass;
```

This way all objects will inherit from myclass object.